# Python Count per hour log file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, logging

I have a python script that displays the Date, hour and IP Address for an attack in a log file. My issue is that i need to be able to count how many attacks occur per hour per day but when i implement a count it just counts the total not what i want.

**The log file looks like this:**

```
Feb  3 08:50:39 j4-be02 sshd[620]: Failed password for bin from 211.167.103.172 port 39701 ssh2
Feb  3 08:50:45 j4-be02 sshd[622]: Failed password for invalid user virus from 211.167.103.172 port 41354 ssh2
Feb  3 08:50:49 j4-be02 sshd[624]: Failed password for invalid user virus from 211.167.103.172 port 42994 ssh2
Feb  3 13:34:00 j4-be02 sshd[666]: Failed password for root from 85.17.188.70 port 45481 ssh2
Feb  3 13:34:01 j4-be02 sshd[670]: Failed password for root from 85.17.188.70 port 46802 ssh2
Feb  3 13:34:03 j4-be02 sshd[672]: Failed password for root from 85.17.188.70 port 47613 ssh2
Feb  3 13:34:05 j4-be02 sshd[676]: Failed password for root from 85.17.188.70 port 48495 ssh2
Feb  3 21:45:18 j4-be02 sshd[746]: Failed password for invalid user test from 62.45.87.113 port 50636 ssh2
Feb  4 08:39:46 j4-be02 sshd[1078]: Failed password for root from 1.234.51.243 port 60740 ssh2
Feb  4 08:39:55 j4-be02 sshd[1082]: Failed password for root from 1.234.51.243 port 34124 ssh2
```

**the code i have so far is:**

```
import re

myAuthlog=open('auth.log', 'r') #open the auth.log for reading
for line in myAuthlog: #go through each line of the file and return it to the variable line
ip_addresses = re.findall(r'([A-Z][a-z]{2}\s\s\d\s\d\d).+Failed password for .+? from (\S+)', line)

print ip_addresses
```

**the outcome is as shown**

```
[('Feb  5 08', '5.199.133.223')]
[]
[('Feb  5 08', '5.199.133.223')]
[]
[('Feb  5 08', '5.199.133.223')]
[]
[('Feb  5 08', '5.199.133.223')]
[]
[('Feb  5 08', '5.199.133.223')]
```

Comment: why not pull the hour out as well and then you can store the day and hour as a key and all the ip addresses as the value. Then use `Counter()` to count the number of ip addresses

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Script to view attacks per hour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559183/python-script-to-view-attacks-per-hour). You should edit your previous question to reflect changes, not create a new one.

Comment: i took away the count as i couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The python function [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) will group your items according to any criteria you specify.

This code will print the number of attacks per hour, per day:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('auth.log') as myAuthlog:
    for key, group in groupby(myAuthlog, key = lambda x: x[:9]):
        print "%d attacks in hour %s"%(len(list(group)), key)
```

Or, with an additional requirement from the comments:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('auth.log') as myAuthlog:
    myAuthlog = (line for line in myAuthlog if "Failed password for" in line)
    for key, group in groupby(myAuthlog, key = lambda x: x[:9]):
        print "%d attacks in hour %s"%(len(list(group)), key)
```

Or, with different formatting:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('auth.log') as myAuthlog:
    myAuthlog = (line for line in myAuthlog if "Failed password for" in line)
    for key, group in groupby(myAuthlog, key = lambda x: x[:9]):
        month, day, hour = key[0:3], key[4:6], key[7:9]
        print "%s:00 %s-%s: %d"%(hour, day, month, len(list(group)))
```

Comment: Thanks this works but the only issue is that it goes through every item in the log file and i need to only show the attacks that state 'Failed password for' is there any way of implementing this?

Comment: Many Thanks, is there any way of editing the print bit as it looks a little weird when it prints out 172 attacks in hour Feb  3 08.

Comment: Sure, there are lots of ways to format the result. I didn't include that because that really unrelated to the question you asked. Regardless, see my recent edit.

Comment: or just display the date, hour, ip address and how many attacks there was

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
from datetime import datetime as dt

answer = collections.defaultdict(int)
with open('path/to/logfile') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        stamp = line[:9]
        t = dt.strptime(stamp, "%b\t%d\t%H")
        answer[t] += 1
```

Comment: FYI, this showed up in the Low Quality Posts queue...probably because it is code only